# how fix ts(7053) typescript error 'The element is implicitly of type 'any', since an expression of type 'string' cannot be used for indexing of type'

Tags: typescript

Writing a function

```
   type CleanAddres = {
   ...
       city?: string;
   }
   type AddressNewData = {
          ...
          id?: number;
   };

function getAddres(addres: AddresNewData[], cleanedAddres: CleanAddres) => {
        const newAddres = Object.keys(cleanedAddres).map((key, i) => {
            const { id } = addres[i] as Clients.AddresNewData;
            return {
                id: id || 0,
                ...cleanedAddres[key] // this is ts(7053) error
            };
        });

}
```

And I get an error "The element is implicitly of type 'any', since an expression of type 'string' cannot be used for indexing of type 'CleanAddres'. An index signature with a parameter of type "string" was not found in the 'CleanAddres' type. ts(7053)"
I tried doing this:

```
map((key: keyof cleanedAddres, i)
```

and

```
const newAddres = Object.keys(cleanedAddres).map((key, i) => {
...
 const key1 = key as keyof cleanedAddres
        return {
            id: id || 0,
            ...cleanedAddres[key1] // this is ts(2698) error
        };
    });
```

How to fix a typing error?

Answer (score 0):

What about `cleanedAddres[+key]` ?

Comment: ]no, the cleanedAddres[+key code does not fix the error